# Solr 7.3.1 won't start "SSL_PORT_PROP" was unexpected at this time

Tags: powershell, ssl, solr, lucene

Downloaded solr 7.3.1 and placed in C:\Program Files (x86)/ upon trying to start or running the examples in powershell I am getting the following error. I was not able to find logs. Thanks in advance.

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\solr-7.3.1\bin> .\solr start

\solr-7.3.1\server\logs\solr_gc.log" -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -Xss256k
 !SSL_PORT_PROP!" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when running the command from CMD?

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was a problem with having the Solr files in "Program Files (86)". It had to do with a permission issue. Since Solr actively updates the files in that folder it is not meant to be in "Program Files (86)". Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was a problem with having the Solr files in "Program Files (86)". It had to do with a permission issue. Since Solr actively updates the files in that folder it is not meant to be in "Program Files (86)". Thanks for the response.